# Placing text in a background header

Tags: html, css

I have a bigger HTML header containing a menu and a large picture.

I would like to place text on the image somewhere as a "title" to the page.

Whenever I try to add my `<h1>` tag somewhere, it positions the text above the menu and it's not what I want.

I would like to be able to position any form of tags somewhere in the picture and I am struggling to find a solution as my code is not efficient to do this.

I am starting to understand what my problem is but I cannot find a solution.

Here is a template of [what's going on](https://gyazo.com/23553ad3d5bf87f03494d3aafee57338). I want to place the text somewhere next to my face (as weird as it sounds lol), anyone?

```css
body {
  font: 15px/1.5 Gravity, Arial;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  background: url('../img/web_bg.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}

.logo {
  line-height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  float: left;
  margin: 16px 46px;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

nav {
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 60px;
}

nav ul {
  line-height: 60px;
  list-style: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 40px;
  transition: 1s;
}

nav.black ul {
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 100;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 16px 40px;
  ;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 16px;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #white;
  border: none;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.menu-icon {
  line-height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  text-align: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<header id="home">
  <h1>MOHANAD ARAFE</h1>
  <nav>
    <div class="menu-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="logo">MOHANAD ARAFE</div>
    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Can you explain the problem specifying what elements of the code are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

You are going good, cheers for that. For the problem you are facing I would suggest you to play with **z-index**. It is a CSS property, and defines the elements as layers. Element with greater z-index will be the top most layers, followed by the elements with lesser z-index. I would suggest you to set z-indec of image to lowest, and make the content above in another container, and set the z-index of this container to a higher range, this should solve your problem.

[Here's more reference on z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using grid in these kind of situations where you have to deal with position of elements. A crash course on grid will be the best option. I personally use it a lot and don't have to care about anything other than z index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use position: absolute; for the h1 tag and use top value in %, and left value in %

```
h1{
  position:absolute; 
  top: value in %;
  left: value in %;
  }
header{
   position:relative;      
  }
```

Note: apply a class name for h1 and apply css for that class or else it might affect h1 tag in sub pages.

Comment: Hi, this seems to work but I am having a problem with the responsive side of things. When I decrease the size of the window, the text moves all over the place due to % values.

Comment: you need to change % values in media queries for mobile devices, https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/css3-media-queries.php